ModelBuilder Entity in ASP.NET Core MVC
In ASP.NET Core 6, I need to rename the database model of ASP.NET Core Identity. I do not use APIs, but just ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.
This my code:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(up => up.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins", "dbo");
}

Program file code:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

AppUser class:
public partial class User : IdentityUser

But I get an error at this line of code in Program file:
var app = builder.Build();

These are the error details:

System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]
Inner exception 1: InvalidOperationException: error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.
Inner exception 2: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore6[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,School.Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken1[System.String]]'.


Can you confirm the correct inheritance for you dbContext is ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser> and that you registered your dbContext in Program.cs correctly?

Yes, I updated my post, you can see it now

But the AppUser class is in another layer Model layer

Ensure that whether you are using program.cs directly for configurations or a separate extensions class, that you have registered your dbContext and added Identity this way:
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity(options =>
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores();

Yes, ApplicationDbContext is in separate extensions class in another layer

If you're having a custom AppUser, you will also need to do the same for all related classes such as IdentityUserRole. Also, you will need to use IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim> for your context, and also apply the changes to UserManager and SignInManager as well.

@iSR5, Yes, I made all required changes but I get the same error, can you help me please - it is not easy to do it -  I feel I am lost here -  can you please give me the complete code as a solution?

@MrMustafa022 which net version are you using?

The version is ASP.NET Core 6

Hi @MrMustafa022, does the exception get when app runs? I cannot reproduce the issue when testing your current code. Maybe it is better for you to share a minimal repo which could reproduce the issue.

Your main issue is that you didn't register the required services with the custom AppUser. You need to register UserManager, RoleManager and UserClaimsPrincipalFactory as Scoped services with the new AppUser model. Not sure if I missed something here, but to have a full control on identity models, you will have to implement custom model for each identity model and inherit from its original model. Also, you will have to implement custom UserManager and RoleManager and also UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.
Here is how to override the default Identity (.NET 6+) (here I use int as TKey instead of string you can use string if you like)  :
Identity Models
public sealed class ApplicationIdentityRole : IdentityRole<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityUser : IdentityUser<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

public sealed class ApplicationIdentityUserToken : IdentityUserToken<int> { }

Identity Managers
public sealed class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationIdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationIdentityUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationIdentityUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationIdentityUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationIdentityUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationIdentityUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }
}

public sealed class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationIdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationIdentityRole> store, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationIdentityRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<RoleManager<ApplicationIdentityRole>> logger) : base(store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
    {
    }
}


public sealed class ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationIdentityUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationIdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationIdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> options) : base(userManager, roleManager, options)
    {
    }
}

IdentityDbContext
public sealed class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationIdentityUser, ApplicationIdentityRole, int, ApplicationIdentityUserClaim, ApplicationIdentityUserRole, ApplicationIdentityUserLogin, ApplicationIdentityRoleClaim, ApplicationIdentityUserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUser>().ToTable("IdentityUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityRole>().ToTable("IdentityRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityRoleClaim>().ToTable("IdentityRoleClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserRole>().ToTable("IdentityUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("IdentityUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("IdentityUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityUserToken>().ToTable("IdentityUserTokens");

    }
}

DI Services
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationIdentityUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>(options => 
{ 
    // set Identity options here
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()                
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()  
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

You can explore the rest of the options that already provided via the service collection (e.g. AddSignInManager), to have an idea on the configurable options.

Hello iSR5, but I get this error: The relationship from 'RoleClaim' to 'Role' with foreign key properties {'RoleId' : int}
cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string}
because it is not compatible.

The RoleId is string in RoleClaim and the Id in Role is string also

@MrMustafa022 change int to string for  all Identity Models in the examples above. That should solve the issue.

Yes, it works right but I get error: SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserId1'. Invalid column name 'UserId1'.

I am using this code to change Id to UserId:  modelBuilder.Entity().Property(up => up.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

@MrMustafa022 I don't recommend changing the primary key name; because everything is linked to it. Plus, UserId is a foreign key name. as foreign key naming convention would use the table name as prefix, and column name as suffix (e.g. UserId). While Id is the most used and known primary key for any table in any database.

@MrMustafa022 if there is no way to avoid that, then you will need to change the FK for every related tables such as UserRole, UserClaims, UserLogins and so on.

No problem I change it to Id and it works right - but I get error: UserManager is Null

The code:   public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
get
{
return _userManager;
}
private set
{
_userManager = value;
}
}

public sealed class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager
{
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore store, IOptions optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
{
}
}

public partial class User : IdentityUser

builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
